# Correct random factor structure in mixed-level model

Tags: mixed-model

I have data wherein mice have been subject to a study multiple times, the repetitions were 4 trials per mouse.

Is the correct random structure, presuming random intercepts, (1 | Mouse) or (1 | Mouse/Trial), where trial is nested within mouse. My first guess would be that nesting trials within mouse would be overspecifying.

Comment: Were the mice nested within trials or the other way around?

Comment: 4 trials per mouse.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. Did you start the first trial and then tested all the mice, then started another trial etc? Or did you select a mouse and perform the trials one after another? Or something else?

Comment: Each mouse went through trial 1, then the procedure was repeated for trial 2, etc.

Comment: So the mice were nested within trials then, in that case you would do 1|Trial/Mouse.